# I can't get extra config attributes from a VM using ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware

I'm using vmware module for ansible 2.8 with success. I'm able to set hotadd attributes to a VM, like this:

```
- name: Set hotadd to "{{ vm_name }}"
  vmware_guest:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_ip }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: False
    uuid: "{{ vm_facts.instance.hw_product_uuid }}"
    hardware:
      hotadd_cpu: true
      hotadd_memory: true
  delegate_to: "localhost"
```

However, I can't get the current status of hotadd attributes from a VM using *vmware_guest_facts*:

```
- name: Get VM "{{ vm_name }}" uuid
  vmware_guest_facts:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_ip }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: False
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
    name: "{{ vm_name }}"
  register: vm_facts
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Output from previous task doesn't include extra config from VM.

Is there a proper way to get this info using ansible?

Comment: Are you sure your custom fields are not in [`vm_facts.customvalues`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.0rc2/lib/ansible/module_utils/vmware.py#L347-L358)?

Comment: No,  I tried with 2.8.0rc2, and no luck: ("customvalues": {},). I think this attributes are not "custom" anyway. This are standard, but extended.